# Factorize in python

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I remember that in the R I did with the.factor (I believe they were factors with levels) but in python I do not know how to do.

It was using get_dummies but it gave a problem when the training dataset had values ​​that the test did not have, thus generating more columns than the ML algorithm was not accepting.

I need to transform the following column:

```
train.head(5)

    Id  MSSubClass  MSZoning
     1      60         RL
     2      53         RR
     3      49         RL
     4      60         RL
     5      95         RR
     6      16         RR
     6      16         R1
```

I need to leave the train.MSZoning as follows:

```
MSZoning
    1
    2
    1
    1
    2
    2
    3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.Categorical`. Following is a minimal reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[1, 60, 'RL'], [2, 53, 'RR'], [3, 49, 'RL'], [4, 60, 'RL'], [5, 95, 'RR']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Id', 'MSSubClass', 'MSZoning']) 

df['MSZoning_factor'] = pd.Categorical(df.MSZoning).codes + 1
df
#   Id  MSSubClass MSZoning  MSZoning_factor
#0   1          60       RL                1
#1   2          53       RR                2
#2   3          49       RL                1
#3   4          60       RL                1
#4   5          95       RR                2
```

Or with `pd.factorize`

```
df['MSZoning_factor'] = pd.factorize(df.MSZoning)[0] + 1
```

giving the same result.